# How to check the user's link to an account with two domain names?

Tags: regex

How to validate user profile URL with two domain names. For example, there are sites that are available from some domains. The same site opens with many domain names. For example I can visit to https://website.com with https://wb.com too. In this case URL's to user profiles can be with two domains:

- https://website.com/username
- https://wb.com/username

I can individually check these domains with two different patterns:

**For:** https://website.com/username

```
(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www.)?website.com\/(?:(?:\w)*#!\/)?([\w\-]*)?
```

**For:** https://wb.com/username

```
(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www.)?wb.com\/(?:(?:\w)*#!\/)?([\w\-]*)?
```

How to create a single template to check the link to the user profile?

Comment: `(?:website|wb)`? Also note that your `.`s there is matching *any character*, not just literal dots, and `https?` is a bit nicer than `(?:http|https)`

Comment: @CertainPerformance, see pattern: `(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www.)?(?:website|wb).com\/(?:(?:\w)*#!\/)?([\w\-]*)?`. Not have any errors in the pattern?

Comment: Yep, `.` still matches *any character*, not just literal dots

Comment: @CertainPerformance, Correct me and write your best option then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using alternation to match `website` or `wb`, and refactoring the regex to remove unnecessary groups and such, you can use:

```
(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:wb|website)\.com\/(?:\w*#!\/)?([\w-]*)?
```

Note that because `.` matches *any character*, you need to escape it with a `\` in front.

https://regex101.com/r/BCbmEw/1

Separated out:

```
(?:https?:\/\/)?
(?:www\.)?
(?:wb|website)\.com\/
(?:\w*#!\/)?
([\w-]*)?
```

Comment: Note that this will provide a positive match on `website.com/` or `wb.com/` so you may end up without username and need to account for that in whatever context the regex is used in.

Comment: Yep, the username group was optional in OP's regex too, so I assumed it was deliberate and used the same logic. (if it's not optional, OP just needs to remove the final `?`)

Comment: @CertainPerformance, here when user type `website.com/` without profile name in url regex no match this error. How solve it and accept as truel only with username

Comment: @AndreasHunter As you can see in the above comment, your original code made the username optional because you used `?`, which makes the preceding token optional. If you want it to be required, remove the final `?` from the regex.

Comment: @CertainPerformance see to the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/BCbmEw/5) regex and tell me why match url when not entered **username** after `website.com/`

Comment: @CertainPerformance As you say I deleted `?` from the end regex but it is not work

Comment: @AndreasHunter Oops, the last group's character set is repeating with `*`, not `+`, so even if it's required, it might not have any characters - change to `+` and it should work. https://regex101.com/r/BCbmEw/6

Answer (score 0):

Your regex would probably have to be programmatic if it were to include any username (I'm using Bash to check my work here, so, for name sakes, I'm going with `{username}` where that is the desired username of the person I want. I'm also going to safely assume all URLs you desire are in that format.

My methodology of testing sites is also to use a text file named `sites.txt` and my methodology of testing the regex is to run `cat sites.txt | grep '{expression}'`.

My expression is, where, again, `{username}` is our desired username:

```
.*\/{username}$
```

For example, for the username `username`, my expression would be:

```
.*\/username$
```

Or, for your name of Andreas Hunter, yours might be `ahunter1`, and the resulting expression would be:

```
.*\/ahunter1$
```

The reason why I mention programmatic regex is; say you're doing this from within a program, and your language has a method/plugin/library or something that checks every item in an array or every line in a file, and on an exact match, it returns `true`, otherwise `false`.

If you were doing this in Java and your method was running on a string `str`, and the method was a method of `String` that was called `isRegexMatch(String)`, and your username that you're checking against is another `String` called `username`, your method call would look like:

```
str.isRegexMatch(".*\\/" + username + "$");
```

Comment: I'm also not checking for exact website URLs; this is to accommodate any website, including `localhost` or an IP address, or for different sites' different folder structures.